# Is there any problem if one of secondary windings is left floating in a flyback converter

Tags: flyback

Is there any problem if we leave one of the secondaries in a flyback converter floating?
I have two secondaries: 24V & 18V.  My application needs only 24V.  What happens if the 18V winding is left floating?

Comment: For EMI reasons, I would at least connect one of the winding outputs to the sec. side ground so that only the hot terminal is left unconnected.

Answer (score 2):

> *What happens if the 18V winding is left floating?*

All windings will float - that's the beauty of a flyback design so, if in fact you mean you want to leave the 18 volt winding unconnected to anything then...

There shouldn't be any problem in a standard flyback circuit providing that the 24 volt output is properly connected and, the feedback stabilization is from the 24 volt DC output.